# Mac returns different datetime string than PC

Tags: macos, silverlight, rest, silverlight-4.0

I have a REST api, thats being called from a silverlight client, and when I do a get I'm sending datetimes like this:

```
/getInformation?id={id}&checkFromDate={checkFromDate}
```

where Id is an int and checkFromDate is a Datetime.

When I backend recive these requests from a pc it looks like this:

2012-09-10%2000:00:00

And I'm handling that just fine, but when doing the same request from a mac I get:

2012-09-07%20kl.%2000:00:00%20+02:00

My question is how should I handle this?

Comment: Any idea what the "kl." means?

Comment: I would guess that is language specifik, since kl. is a short in swedish for time.

Comment: How do you format/print {checkFromDate}? Maybe you need an explicit fixed format to avoid locale issues.

Comment: Well i didn't format anything, I just added the datetime to the url, and I think the client then did a tostring before sending, and therefor I got different formated dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Silverlight docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> The ToString() method returns the string representation of the date and time in the calendar used by the current culture.

So this will not be consistent across all your clients (probably has nothing to do with Mac vs PC really).

You need to format the date manually using a fixed format and put that in your URL rather than depending on ToString.

Comment: I added the tostring("s") to the datetime properties before a call to the webservice. This solved the problem, just like you described above